# Why Status Code 404 error message is different in different environment?

Tags: azure, iis, http-status-code-404

We have moved our website from local environment to Azure. But we are getting different error message for error code 404. Below are screen shots.

1. In case of existing website.
   [404 Error message from existing hosted Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6E0e.jpg)
2. After cloud Migration.
   [404 Error message After Migrated to cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRRdJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a 404 error while accessing your custom domain, then you are most likely missing the link between your **Azure App Service Web App configuration and your custom domain**.

For more details, refer: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2013/10/01/404-file-or-directory-not-found-when-mapping-custom-domain-to-a-windows-azure-web-site-server-error/

Comment: I am not getting 404 error. Everything working fine. But in the case if some resources are protected we are sending 404 status code. But with this code messages are not same in existing environment and cloud environment.